# Better understanding JavaScript parameters

Tags: javascript, function

I don't understand some parts of JavaScript code regarding parameters. I found this example on W3schools:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a id="myAnchor" href="http://w3schools.com/">Go to W3Schools.com</a>

<p>The preventDefault() method will prevent the link above from following the URL.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("myAnchor").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am confused with `event` parameter inside function. This code works although `event` parameter didn't become an argument, that is, it doesn't have any value. How can this "empty" parameter be used with a method. Why this code works? I am new to JavaScript so any simple answer would be appreciate.

Comment: When the browser calls the function, it'll pass in a value for the parameter.

Comment: @Pointy: What kinde of value?

Comment: The browser will pass in an event object. That code is setting up an event handler.

Comment: I usually have problems in IE if not I pass the event as parameter...

Answer (score 0):

Slit,

The function which is being called on "click" event is a "call-back" function. Once the event "click" raises then the anonymous "call-back" function which is "function(event){" is being called immediately with 1 parameter which is "event". In order to determine the parameters which will the anonymous function called with you should refer to documentation.
After you find the parameters, you may use and work with them inside this function, for example add "event.preventDefault(); alert('test')" and nothing will happen when you click on element, only popup window with "test" will arise.

Don't hesitate to ask any questions so I can improve my answer.. Just tried to explain in high level.

Comment: I think I got it. Word "event" gets value "click" because that is how addEventListener works. If it was "doubleclick", then word "event" would have that value. I have hard time reading JavaScript manuals, I don't understand explanations. On Mozilla's page it says event.preventDefault() and I didn't understand what this "event" means. Like I always confused a bit "element","HTMLElement",  "node" or "object".

Comment: Slit, not exactly. When event "click" raises, then anonymous function is being called using "event" object as parameter. It's not a word or string or other... It's an object. Using this object you may control what should happen when click event arise. As I mentioned in my answer, you may prevent all default "thing" which usually happens.. For example, when you are clicking on a link, then you are being redirected to URL, when you click "Submit" then you are submitting form.. or you may just "append" to default "thing" your specific logic like showing popup "test".

Comment: But this 'event' isn't reservd word, because I can change it to 'XYZ' and it stil works.

Comment: The "event" it's an argument to function which you may refer to in the "body" of your function. The "click" event passes 1 parameter to anonymous function and then in the "body" of your function you may refer to it...

Answer (score 0):

This function is also known as a callback. A callback is when you pass one function as an argument to another.

Try testing this code and then click anywhere on the page:

```
window.addEventListener("click", click);

function click() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

If you open the console you should see `[MouseEvent]`. The special `arguments` object returns all the arguments received by the function. The `click` function received only one argument `MouseEvent` because the window method `addEventListener` sends an event to the event handler.

Here's a similar example:

```
init("abc", logArgs); //--> "abc"
init("abc", logDog); //--> "dog"

function logArgs(x) {
    console.log(x);
}

function logDog(x) {
    console.log("dog");
}

function init(x, callback) {
    callback(x);
}
```

The confusing part about your example is that you can send a function an anonymous function. An anonymous function is one that is not named. Using the above example, you could do this:

```
init("abc", function(y) { //the y parameter comes from the init function
    console.log(y); //"abc"
});

function init(x, callback) {
    callback(x); //send the first argument to the anonymous function
}
```